# Elasticsearch cloud hosted end point not open in my browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, cloud, elastic-stack

Elastic search cloud hosted end point url not opening.
For others it is opening and asking for username and password but for me not.
I tested this by creating new trail elastic cloud account, that end point also not opening.
But for others and in my mobile browser it is opening.
I tried to open with other browser on my system, that also not worked.
If anyone faced this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, It happens sometimes due to some misconfiguration, mostly **if you are using AWS cloud services** ( or may be other reason, I am not sure).

Solution to this problem is,

1. Delete your current deployment.
2. Create New Deployment using **Google Cloud Services**

**Note:** Now don't infer by yourself that Gcloud is better that AWS or AWS is not that good. Many factors are there to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer may be this.

I found this error, while running elastic search in desktop

```
"reason":"action [cluster:monitor/main] requires authentication",
"header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Bearer realm=\"security\""
```

It says that requires authentication header. So May be a reason that you are on some proxy VPN. It can alter your access.

To solve it, close/turn off your proxy and then, `reboot` your deployment.

Hope, It helps!